# wget can not save asp pages

Tags: asp.net, wget

It seems that `wget` is not able to get `asp` files while it has no problem with `html`. I have wrote a script to wget some URLs and save them in `csv` format. 
The script is

```
wget -qO- http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KPAPALMY1&format=1 | sed 's+<br />++g' > $1.csv
```

Comment: Can you post your whole script?  Also:  `wget`ing that page works fine for me.  But the page the server returns isn't in CSV format - there are extraneous `<br>` tags thrown in, and each line seems to end with an unnecessary comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put quotes around that URL!  Left unquoted, Bash (or whatever shell you're using) sees the `&` as a request to run `wget` in the background - and the format parameter, which comes after the `&` is never sent to the server.  Try this instead:

```
wget -qO- 'http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KPAPALMY1&format=1' | sed 's+<br>++g' > $1.csv
```

Note that I tweaked your `sed` command, too - the `<br>`s you're getting don't have the terminating slash.  Also:  Deleting those `<br>`s means that only every *other* line has data.  Hopefully that won't be a problem, as deleting newlines with `sed` is a bit of a pain, but if it is, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251999/589985) for how to do it.

Hope that helps!